# Update attributes before_save callback not saving extra attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes, callback

I'm using a before_save callback method to set an attribute to true if a number of other attributes are not 0. The callback is called when I update my model but the extra attribute isn't set. I think it might be because that attribute isn't passed to the update method. How do I work round that?

Controller

```
@blog.update(blog_params)
```

Model

```
before_save do
  self.indicator = true unless attribute_1 == "0" && attribute_2 == "0"
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You might consider using `before_validation` instead. Rails will call the`before_validation` callback before it calls `before_save`, so if you need to make sure you're setting a value, that would be the place to do so.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fair enough David.

Answer (score 4):

Try to put `true` after all code

```
before_save do
  self.indicator = true unless attribute_1 == "0" && attribute_2 == "0"
  true
end
```

all callbacks should return true in any way

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. It turns out my code actually was updating the attribute I was looking at the wrong record in the database. Embarrassing!

Comment: This is such a nice pitfall in Rails - I'd call this a bug - before_save is not a validation!